# How to find the optimal cp value in rpart doing cross validation manually?

Tags: r, cross-validation, rpart

I'd like to test two classifiers at the same time, that is logistic regression and classification trees. To find a classification threshold, which for example maximises F1-score, I split my data set into train, validation and test set. Because this is all pretty new to me, I wrote my own loop to understand the procedure behind it. I was wondering, how would you find manually (without just using cross-validation from the caret package) the optimal cp-value? Is the optimal cp the average of all the cp picked for each fold? But if so, what do I need the validation set for? In logistic regression, this is more clear to me since I need it to find the threshold which maximises my F1 score. I appreciate your help!